# virtual table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert my sql query to laravel Eloquent . This is the corresponding sql query `

```
select 
distinct reciver from 
(
select u.user_id as reciver,max(created_at)as created_at
 from messages
 m join message_user u on m.id=u.message_id where sender=225 group by reciver 
union
 select m.sender as reciver,max(created_at)as created_at
 from 
messages m join message_user u on m.id=u.message_id 
where u.user_id=225 
group by reciver
)
as chatbox order by created_at desc
```

I tried the following

```
$recived=Message::select(DB::raw('messages.sender as reciver,max(messages.created_at)as created_at'))
->join('message_user','messages.id','=','message_user.message_id') 
->where("message_user.user_id",'=',$request->user()->id)
->groupBy('reciver');

$sent=Message::select(DB::raw('message_user.user_id as reciver,max(messages.created_at)as created_at'))
->join('message_user','messages.id','=','message_user.message_id')
->where("messages.sender",'=',$request->user()->id)
->groupBy('reciver')
->union($recived);
```

it does not give the required out put it only give union result i want perfom another select query in that table($reciver table)

Comment: You could use `DB::select()` as an alternative to run raw queries in Laravel.

Comment: im trying to implement  Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the `$sent` query you can do something like

```php
    $final = \DB::table($sent, 'chatbox')
    ->select('reciver')
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->get();
```

PS: I have used similar approach lately to achieve such thing, it may not work for you as you need, but I am sure you can